# Custom property binding @Input not working

Tags: angular

I am creating custom property in one `component` which I want to access in another `component` through **@Input()** but its not working getting nothing in the second component not even displaying the initial value of **result(custom property)**, I am not getting any error in console, I have also searched solutions online, find some, but can't get it to work.

Please help me out, Here is my **code**.

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wvp03S6V3w67dqf351RV?p=preview) created by a user in the comments.

**property-binding-component.ts (Child)**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-binding',
  template: `
      {{result}} //value working here 
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class PropertyBindingComponent{
   @Input() result: number = 5000; 
}
```

**UPDATED**
**databindings-components.ts(parent)**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-databindings',
  templateUrl: './databindings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./databindings.component.css']
})
export class DatabindingsComponent {
}
```

**databindings-component.html (Parent)**

```
<app-property-binding [result]="300">   </app-property-binding>
//not working here not event showing the value `5000`
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DatabindingsComponent } from './databindings/databindings.component';
import { PropertyBindingComponent } from './databindings/property-binding.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DatabindingsComponent, PropertyBindingComponent ],
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule
 ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

**Thanks**

Comment: When you remove `[result]="300"` does it show `5000`? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no its not showing anything! no errors in console everything works fine.

Comment: Can you please try adding a constructor to `PropertyBindingComponent` `constructor() { console.log('PropertyBindingComponent created'); }` and check if this is printed?

Comment: Could you post the snippet where you use the `DatabindingsComponent`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah thats printing in console. i will share my databindings-component.ts

Comment: @HarryNinh i have updated my question with `databindings-component.ts`

Comment: Can't reproduce https://plnkr.co/edit/Wvp03S6V3w67dqf351RV?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your plunker is working but issue remains the same.. shows 300 as databinded in template but not when binded to property show nothing.

Comment: I don't understand "t when binded to property show nothing." Is the Plunker not doing what you want or does it just not work locally?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer apologies! its working in plunker but not in local.

Comment: On local machine it works fine

Comment: Seems to be something with your local setup.

Answer (score 0):

The Plunker demo works fine. I'm guessing a reason:

Check your local setup.

1. Check "app.module.ts" file and see if there are any typos in import and declarations parts.
2. Check your spelling for "property-binding-component.ts" file (What you typed in your question), which should be "property-binding.component.ts".
3. Check your "databindings-component.html" file, and double check whether the selector name matches or not. (Since you can't even see the "5000").